# Value too large for defined data type

Tags: mount, android, arch-linux, chroot

I am following this guide on how to chroot arch linux in my android device. [Welcome back gnu! - My revenge on Android](http://devwithopinions.blogspot.ca/2012/06/welcome-back-gnu-my-revenge-on-android.html?m=1)

In case you do not read the guide, I made a linux.img file on my pc, using dd command and then formatting it to ext2 partition like this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of="$img" obs=1M seek=2048 count=0
$ mkfs.ext2 -F "$img"
```

So, I transfer this image on my phone, follow other steps that do not concern us and get to a point where I mount the image on loop like this:

```
losetup /dev/loop256 "$img"
```

And this is where things go wrong. I now get error "value too large for defined data type". Damn, now what?

Is there any almighty developper that can possibly help?
Any, ANY help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Hope this time this post gets attention not just for the typos and grammar mistakes but someone will answer since my other posts got like 4 corrections and not a single response even after so much time.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there’s no reason to use loop device 256. Use something less. Like 5 or whatever. The number of available loop devices could be limited.

You can list active loop devices using `losetup -l` and find the first free device using `losetup -f`

Comment: Tried it but no luck. I get same error for loop5, loop255 and 3-5 other loops i tried. And the first free is loop0

Comment: So I gather you executed the `losetup` command on your phone, right? You might want to try a small image and work your way towards the limit. Apparently, `losetup` sometimes doesn’t support large files.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for responding again. But see, I tried it with smaller image and still no luck! My device supports loop devices. And yes I did on phone.